# How to read a file in smalltalk byte-wise?

Tags: smalltalk

I have found documentation about reading files in Smalltalk line by line, but I need to read it character by character. How do we do this in Smalltalk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful if you would identify the dialect of Smalltalk (Squeak, Pharo, VisualWorks, VA, GemStone, etc.). In any case, whatever class you found that has a #'nextLine' method should also have a #'next' method that answers a single character.

Comment: @Dan There has been another question about bit accessing and bit manipulation recently. Please use the search to find it. If the answers there do not suffice, please ask a new question.